# ShawnLin numberpicker library for Android - how to make the text vertically aligned?

Tags: android, numberpicker

I'm using Numberpicker library for Android by Shawn Lin. It's link on Github is:

https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker

The numbers in this widget appear as:
[image: Shawn Lin Number picker]

As you can see, the numbers are not centered vertically.

I have been trying to center align the numbers vertically, but it doesn't happen. The library has allowed aligning the text to the left, to the right or to the center (center_horizontal), but there's no option for centering the text vertically. I tried setting the 'gravity'  to 'center', but it doesn't work. I tried setting the padding, but that doesn't work either.

Is there anyway to center the text in this widget vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the np_orientation attribute, and set it to Vertical in your Number Picker tag, just like this:

```
<com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/number_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:np_orientation="vertical"
/>
```

For further information, visit the official [documentation](https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker).

Hope it helps, happy coding!